# Is it normal behaviour that CakePHP creates hundreds of session files in app/tmp/sessions with only a few users?

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I let the system (CakePHP 2.1) run for about two weeks and had to delete thousands and thousands of session files that were just hanging around.  After I deleted them they started to roll in again.  I've let it run for a few hours and I'm up to 426 files.  Is this normal for 10 users in the system?  I have a `robot.txt` file that tells the engines to piss off and I have auth and acl up on https on all pages.  Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'cookie' => 'scsys',
    'timeout' => 600
));
```

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue for me as well. We were getting 1000's of session files a second.

The reason for this is that we have the Session component loaded into the AppCOntroller, and there are a number of cron jobs that hit a url on our site from a remote server, every couple of seconds. Since Cookies are disabled on the server userAgent, a new session had to be created every time the cron ran (a normal userAgent with cookies enabled would use the same session file).

There are two work arounds for this. One is to move the Session component out of the AppController and into the specific controllers you need. The other, which is the solution i've chosen, is to use the php command session_destroy() after each cron that is run. To take it one step further i've made a plugin Cron that has in it Cotroller/CronAppController.php:

```
    /**
    * class to extend if you want the session destroyed after an action has completed. 
    * Useful for limiting cake session file storage overload
    *  
    */


    class CronAppController extends AppController {

        /**
         * set this to true in a controller action if you want the session destroyed 
         */
        public $cronAction = false;

        function afterFilter(){
            parent::afterFilter();
            if($this->cronAction){
                session_destroy();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then extend your controller that has a cron action in it with Cron.CronAppController, then in your action set $this->cronAction = true; and you're good to go!